# Remove a line from file NOT having a specific word in Python

Tags: python, regex, linux, file, replace

Program in Python which,

remove a line starting with `<div` and ending with `>` but NOT having word `text-align` in between it.

Input:

```
<div>
<div><div>
<div style="text-align: center;">
<div kjgueberhfui;hh;ah>
<div kjfh fhefhufh  fhueshf >
<strong>PANKY</strong>
<div style="text-align: left;">
```

Output:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
<strong>PANKY</strong>
<div style="text-align: left;">
```

I am searching for something like:

```
f1 = open('input.txt','r')
filedata = f1.read()
filedata = re.sub("<div[^>]*/^((?!text-align).)*$/[^>]*>","",filedata)
```

OR

```
f1 = open('input.txt','r')
for line in f1:
    if "<div" in line:
        if "text-align" in line;
        else:
            f1.write(line.replace(THIS_LINE,"")
```

The above 2 code are not working or incomplete!

Comment: One issue with your second example is surely that you cannot have an empty `if "text-align" in line:` expression without anything to do in that case. At least, you should provide a `pass` command. Or, use `if not "text-align" in line:`

Answer (score 2):

```
f1 = open('input.txt','r')
for line in f1:
    if "<div" in line:
        if "text-align" in line;
        else:
            f1.write(line.replace(THIS_LINE,"")
```

Doesn't have statement after if, so it can't work. Besides you can combine two conditions:

```
with open('input.txt','r') as f1, open('output.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    for line in f1:
        if not ("<div" in line and "text-align" not in line):
            f2.write(line)
```

Comment: What do write in place of "THIS_LINE" ?

Comment: I've changed this answer. It only copies matching lines now.

Comment: I've updated my answer so that it doesn't change read file on the fly. You would have to make some changes if you want to change it in one run:
1. open it in read-write mode
2. assure read cursor is in proper place hen writing content after it has been read and modified.

Answer (score 2):

You can use startswith and endswith functions of a string.

```
    if line.startswith('<div') & line.endswith('>') & ('text-align' not in line):
        #do something
```

Answer (score 1):

THANKYOU EVERYONE, 
because of you all I was able to figure out my answer,

some of your code output the reverse of what i asked for but here is the code which is the solution to my answer,

```
f1 = open('input.txt','r')
f2 = open('output.txt','w')

for line in f1:
    if "<div" in line and "text-align" in line:
        f2.write(line)
    if "<div" not in line:
        f2.write(line)

f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The more correct and complete answer to this question is something like this:

```
lines = open("input.txt").read().splitlines()

with open("input.txt", "w") as file:
    for line in lines:
        if not (line.startswith("<div") and "text-align" not in line and line.endswith(">")):
            file.write(line + "\n")
```

This would remove all unwanted lines from the `input.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you:

```
with open('input.txt','rb+') as f1:    
    for div in f1:
          if 'text-align' in div or '<div' not in div:
                print(div)
```